# Get the correct local time

Tags: javascript

I need to get the local time. I created this script but, for example, in italy ( where I live ), the alert shows 7 instead of 9. Why ?

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
var seconds = time / 1000;

seconds = seconds % 86400;

hours = parseInt(seconds / 3600);

alert(hours);
```

Comment: `alert( new Date().getHours() )`?

Comment: @Juhana I need to get the hours from getTime because after I have to do others things.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Can't you save the hours to a variable and then do the "other things"?

Comment: it's "wrong" because you don't live in england...

Answer (score 6):

Because `getTime` returns the timestamp in milliseconds. And the timestamp is timezone independent. Use `getTimezoneOffset()` to get the offset in minutes from UTC, and add it.

Answer (score 2):

`new Date().getHours()` will give you the local time, no adjustment needed.

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` will give you the number of minutes from UTC in the users's locale, should you need to offset an absolute time.

Note that UNIX timestamps measure the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch as if every day was exactly 3600 * 24 seconds. That allows you to get the time on most days with divisions and modulos, but if your timestamp is earlier than the latest [leap second](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/unix-leap-seconds.html), and you try to do some simple maths with it, the result will not be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/yk3wkcr8/

```
var currentTime = new Date();

var h = currentTime.getHours();
var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

alert(h);
alert(m);
alert(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example, try this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/706s2cbn/3/)

It uses full array with seconds, minutes, hours, date, day and year.

BTW you can use getHours(); followed by the others.

```
var d = new Date(),
    hours = d.getHours(),
    hour = (hours - 12),
    year = d.getFullYear(),
    second = d.getSeconds(),
    minute = d.getMinutes();
alert (hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
```

etc, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
new Date().toLocaleString()
```

it will give you something like:

```
"4/16/2015, 9:14:53 AM"
```

And if you need to obtain only the time stamp then you can split the resulting string into an array and get the second item from the array:

```
new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[1]
```

If you need only the hours this is the way:

```
 new Date().getHours()
```